# HttpConfiguration method EnableCors not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Enabled CORS on one project, trying to do it on another existing project, however the "EnableCors" method cannot be found in during compilation:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();
```

The exact compile fail error message is

'HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'EnableCors' and no extension method 'EnableCors' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

I've done the same thing in this project as I have the other project:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
```

This project has odata in it though...I'm not sure if that's the major difference making it fail.

Any ideas? I've also tried

```
Update-Package -reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Comment: You are probably missing a `using` statement at the top of the file

Comment: `using System.Web.Http;` is the first line of the file. It's not missing that using statement.

Comment: And `System.Web.Http.Cors` appears in your project references? If so, best luck I've had in these situations is to completely uninstall both packages and install them again. Even the reinstall command has failed me where that's worked.

Comment: Also, OData isn't the culprit, I have a project using both and there are no problems.

Answer (score 5):

I had to reinstall all the packages - THEN the compile error went away.

Weird. I had built & cleaned the project several times.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. What packages did you have to reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

I had this situation today.   Could not find the using libraries.  Tried uniinstalling and reinstalling a couple of times Microsoft.AspNET.WebAPI.Cors as well as Asp.Net.Cors at v5.2.6.    It would compile, but then after I published it showed that the references were lost again...very very odd indeed.  So I took a shot and looked at the Updates in Nuget and one stood out.  Microsoft.Net.Compilers. 2.8.2 and current was 2.9.0.   Updated that one and tried again..boom worked.  Clearly there is a dependency that caused some oddities, I don't begin to profess understanding of that quirk, but thought it might help someone out there.